# Accessing same db with multiple clients - Pattern?

Tags: database, database-design, client-server

I am having trouble finding a pattern/literature on how to make a client-server environment with multiple clients without being bugged with conflicting changes. Does there exits a pattern or some god literature on this concept?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle conflicting changes, unless you want to keep your transaction open during the whole user interaction (hint: you don't want to do that).

The concept to look for is "optimistic locking" or "optimistic concurrency control".

If you already looked into that, you need to explain what specific problem you want to avoid, and why optimistic locking won't work.